# How will this work in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, compiler-errors

I compiled the following code in java and it compiled!
How?
And when i run it it just runs without any output!
Why did it compile?

```
public class Check{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    for(int i=0;i!=0;i++)
    System.out.print(i);

    }
}
```

Comment: What does `i != 0` mean? Do you know how `for` loops work?

Comment: It's not invalid code, just a bit pointless...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It simply means checking that i is a non zero integer!

Comment: @JonK Why does it run? I need it for my own knowledge..

Comment: Right, so since i **is** 0 at loop start up, the `i != 0` test fails, and the loop bails out. End of story.

Comment: `Pascal` had the `until` loop for people like you

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels But why does it compile?

Comment: Why wouldn't it compile?  Just because you code bad behavior doesn't mean it won't compile.

Comment: Because it is syntactically correct code.

Comment: Why shouldn't it compile?

Comment: @coder_A - The compiler doesn't care if your logic is wrong as long as the code is syntactically correct.

Comment: @birryree: "as long as the code is **syntactically** correct". that's the key to the original poster's misunderstanding. They're confused between syntactically correct vs. logically correct. The code has correct compilable syntax, but it does not logically make sense.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Yes, read mine back and I felt it was missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the program "does nothing" as far as the user can see. But the instructions(code) you have given to the compiler does in fact have valid statements in it that are syntactically correct. If there are semantic errors in your program, that is up to us as programmers to sort out. This may be considered a bug - but it is one that us, the coders must find and fix - not the compiler.

Hovercraft full of eels' comment on your post explains nicely why there is no output.